# What should I do if I cannot connect because the storage of cloudsql is full?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, storage, google-cloud-sql

The storage capacity of cloudsql DB is set to a maximum of 64 TB.

The storage currently in use is about 58 TB.

However, the following error occurs in the current log and the connection itself cannot be established.

```
"2022-01-06 02:50:39.648 UTC [34]: [2-1] db=,user= FATAL: could not write to file "pg_wal/xlogtemp.34": No space left on device"
```

It seems to be running out of capacity because it is full.

The point-in-time recovery function seems to be unavailable because the DB is not running. Currently, a new DB is created and the backup data from a few days ago is duplicated.

Is there any other way to recover faster?

Comment: It seems the transaction logs are taking a significant amount of storage and the storage space is running out. I would suggest you to [raise a support ticket](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases#creating_cases) with Google Cloud Platform support as it involves more in-depth analysis.

Comment: I might be missing something here, but why not just increase the size then?  Do you have auto scaling off?

Comment: @MikeKarp - He cannot resize. 64 TB is the maximum support size.